# Moto X Play notifications

Tags: moto-x-play

As everyone knows Moto X Play does not have any LED notification. 
It becomes very difficult without LED notification. You'd need to take your mobile to check of there's any missed call, message or even to check if the battery is full.
There are some apps available which needs root access to enable LED notification. But rooting will void warranty.
Are there any apps available which enables LED notification with out rooting.
Any other tip or trick or apps like ifttt (if that can help) is also welcome.

Comment: The LED on modern Moto devices (although disabled in software) is hardwired to the charging circuit, there is no way to use it as a notification system since software cannot control it other than to say if it's enabled or disabled at which point it will light when charging and that's it... this is what Moto Display is for.

Answer (score 2):

apps like IFTTT are used for automating work by creating a recipe or using the one's already available, it won't help you enable your LED notification light. 
Someone from Motorola Customer Care stated-
"Unfortunately, you can't enable the notification light of your Moto X play, this feature is not available anymore, we have replaced the LED for Active display, It will show notifications as well, the LED that we have included is just for emergency It just light up when your device is full of charge or when It needs charge."

Here's the link for it- 
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-enable-the-notification-light-of-Moto-X-Play

The gist comes out, that you must root your device in order to use the apps available on the Play Store to enable the LED notifications.

hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks yashtheastral. I'm well aware of ifttt and wanted to know of there's any channel that can illuminate LED. I went through that quota post as well. The LED is never used whether it is fully charged or while the charge is almost out. Even if it is lit at sometime I'd like to know if it could be lit any other time or any API for that matter.